# Is it possible to get class of the generic argument?

Tags: java, generics, ormlite

I'm kind of lame with generics, but I wonder, for the following class:

```
static class SomeClass<T> {
 private T value;

 public SomeClass(T value) {
  T.class?
  this.value = value;
 }

 public T getValue() {
  return value;
 }
}
```

If called for example:
`SomeClass<String> stringer = new SomeClass<String>("Hello");`
Is it possible to get `String.class` (or whatever T would be) in the constructor?

Ok, wait a sec, I'm going to explain what I'm trying to solve

The actual problem is that I'm using [OrmLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ormlite/) and I have a lot of DAO objects, like this one:

```
public class PostDAO extends BaseJdbcDao<Post, String> {
    public PostDAO(DatabaseType databaseType) {
        super(databaseType, Post.class);
    }
}
```

For `Domain` it is:

```
public class DomainDAO extends BaseJdbcDao<Domain, String> {
 public DomainDAO(DatabaseType databaseType) {
  super(databaseType, Domain.class);
 }
}
```

and so on. I wanted to parametrize these, so that I can only have one:

```
public class DAO<K, V> extends BaseJdbcDao<K, V> {
 public DAO(DatabaseType databaseType) {
  super(databaseType, (WHAT HERE?));
 }
}
```

but I'm stuck on the `what here` part)

Comment: Why do you want to get the class?

Comment: you can't do `new SomeClass<String>("Hello");` on a `static` class btw.

Comment: @pakore: Maybe you can't but I can. ;) Seriously: It works fine for me and why shouldn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deriving Class from Generic T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801940/deriving-class-from-generic-t)

Comment: I've added a `createDao` method to the `BaseJdbcDao` class in ORMLite version 2.7.  It will allow you to create DOAs without needing a DAO class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
public class DAO<K, V> extends BaseJdbcDao<K, V> {
 public DAO(DatabaseType databaseType, Class databaseClass) {
  super(databaseType, databaseClass);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@pakore's answer is a good one but I wanted to add that you don't *have* to define the per-class DAO object.  I recommended it in the ORMLite documentation but it's supposed to be a convenience, not a pain.

You can always do something like the following using `BaseJdbcDao` as an anonymous class:

```
BaseJdbcDao<Post, String> postDao =
    new BaseJdbcDao<Post, String>(databaseType, Post.class) {
    };
postDao.setDataSource(dataSource);
postDao.initialize();
```

I do that a lot in the ORMLite junit tests.  Might be better to have a utility method like the following.  I've just added it to the `BaseJdbcDao` class which will be in the 2.7 release.

```
public static <T, ID> Dao<T, ID> createDao(DatabaseType databaseType,
    DataSource dataSource, Class<T> clazz) throws SQLException {
    BaseJdbcDao<T, ID> dao = new BaseJdbcDao<T, ID>(databaseType, clazz) {
    };
    dao.setDataSource(dataSource);
    dao.initialize();
    return dao;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

value.getClass() should do the trick (assuming value is never null!)

Comment: Then you can't. This information is only available at compile time. At runtime there is just `Object`.

Comment: I think that BaseJdbcDao has the class argument as parameter because you can not get the class from the type parameter.

As Dao is not a concrete class itself, you can add the class parameter there too.

Comment: even if `value` is not null, it may still not give the answer you wanted, as `value` could be of any subclass of `T`