# InvalidClassException: No valid constructor

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, objectify

When I run app in localhost, it work, but when deploy to GAE, throw the following error:

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/Login
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:268)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:57)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:39)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.loadSession(SessionManager.java:327)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:301)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.getHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:237)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.setRequestedId(SessionHandler.java:246)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:730)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:396)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:396)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:55)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:488)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:327)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:564)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1649)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1562)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
... 46 more
W 2013-09-19 21:44:19.795
Nested in javax.servlet.ServletException:     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:57)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:39)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.loadSession(SessionManager.java:327)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:301)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.getHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:237)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.setRequestedId(SessionHandler.java:246)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:730)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:396)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1043)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2012)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1936)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1395)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:396)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.SessionManagerUtil.deserialize(SessionManagerUtil.java:55)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: br.com.myapp.dao.MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:488)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:327)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:564)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1649)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1562)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
... 46 more
```

In MercadoriaMbean.java:

```
public class MercadoriaMBean implements Serializable {

private MercadoriaDAO dao;

public MercadoriaMBean() {
    dao = new MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl();
    fillMercadorias();
}
```

MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl.java:

```
public class MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl extends AbstractObjectifyDAO<Mercadoria>
    implements Serializable, MercadoriaDAO {

public MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl() {
    super(Mercadoria.class);
}
```

AbstractObjectifyDAO.java:

```
public class AbstractObjectifyDAO<T extends AbstractEntity> {

private Class<T> clazz;

public AbstractObjectifyDAO(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

**EDIT**

Using Reflection:

```
    public AbstractObjectifyDAO(String clazz) {

    ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    try {
        this.clazz = (Class<T>) myClassLoader.loadClass(clazz);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Throwing error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class hierarchy for class br.com.myapp.model.Mercadoria has no @Entity annotation
```

In AbstractObjectifyDAO.class:

```
    public List<T> getAll() {
    return ofy().load().type(clazz).list();
}
```

I checked that Mercadoria.class have @Entity annotation.

Comment: How are you trying to instantiate MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl ?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from the stack trace is that the error occurs when `MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl` is being deserialized. Deserialization needs the class to have no-args constructor which is true for `MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl` and the class to have serialVersionUID.

From the Java Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) :

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   [InvalidClassException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html). A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long.

I do not see `serialVersionUID` in `MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl` so if it's missing you may try to add it first and see if it solves the problem.

If it's there or it does not solve the problem try and remove the parameter `Class<T> clazz` from the `AbstractObjectifyDAO` constructor and obtained `clazz` using reflection and see if the problem will be solved or let's see what the error will be in this case.

Comment: Using serial Id not worked, but when I set this.clazz = Mercadoria.class; worked! But I try use reflection for keep generic code to all Models.

Comment: @vctlzac The idea of using reflection is to make `AbstractObjectifyDAO` has no-args constructor. Remove the string parameter and use reflection to get class from T the generic parameter of the class itself.

Comment: @vctlzac I also suspect something else .. are you sure all fields of `MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl` are serializable ?

Comment: Actually MercadoriaDAOOfyImpl  has no fields. Only Mercadoria.java has fields and all are serializable.
The odd is that the initial code work in localhost, but crash on GAE. I'm trying use reflection with T. Thanks for now!

Comment: Mercadoria is the objectify Entity right ? I understand the need for it to be serialized to the client but why is the DAO class being serialized too ? shouldn't it be in server only ?

Comment: Perhaps it is an internal process of the GAE. I can not understand well.

Comment: May be that using T to load class is not possible. Look It:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801940/deriving-class-from-generic-t

Comment: I think your architecture should be simpler. using Objectify with GAE is really simple and you do not need all these classes. just make your objectify entities and expose methods to the client via RPC service like in GWT or REST using Google Cloud Endpoint.

Comment: I'll think about your suggestion.
But I based this project: https://github.com/yaw/jsf2-gae
I only added generics in entities for not have need rewriting methods common to all, as "getAll", "findById", "save", etc..

Comment: Take a look at this example http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/ it's similar to what you want to do .. the problem you have is due to something on the client calling server class it should not be able to access .. but I cannot it from the code you posted.